# XSLT: Pass variable into template when using apply-templates

Tags: xslt, symphony-cms

I'm not sure if this is asking too much of XSLT, but I'm after something similar to how `mode` works, except ideally within one template, rather than having to duplicate it as I am now:

```
<!-- Start -->
<xsl:apply-templates select="airports/airport" mode="start" />

<!-- End -->
<xsl:apply-templates select="airports/airport" mode="end" />

<!-- Template -->
<xsl:template match="airports/airport" mode="start">
    <option value="{@iata}" data-alternative-spellings="{.},{@iata}">
        <xsl:if test="@iata = 'LGW'">
            <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="@iata"/> - <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </option>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="airports/airport" mode="end">
    <option value="{@iata}" data-alternative-spellings="{.},{@iata}">
        <xsl:if test="@iata = 'LAX'">
            <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="@iata"/> - <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </option>
</xsl:template>
```

The template applies the `selected` attribute if the value is something specific. This value needs to be different depending on what's calling the template. There are two cases, `start` and `end` that both have different criteria.

The easiest way to explain what I'm attempting to do is for me to write it in another language :)

```
<!-- Start -->
getAirports(start);

<!-- End -->
getAirports(end);

<!-- Template -->
var getAirports = function(position)
{
    var selected = '';
    switch(position)
    {
        case 'start':
            if(iata == 'LGW')
            {
                var selected = 'selected="selected"';
            }
        break;
        case 'end':
            if(iata == 'LAX')
            {
                var selected = 'selected="selected"';
            }
        break;
        default:
        break;
    }
    return '<option value="'+iata+'" data-alternative-spellings="'+iata+','+name+'" '+selected+'>'+iata+' - '+name+'</option>';
}
```

Is this possible in xslt, or will I have to stick to duplicating the template and using `mode`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A fellow Twitter user gave me the solution, which can be found in this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/greystate/69639edd5107cbbe43c6).

What I needed was `with-param`, something I've never used before:

```
<!-- Start -->
<xsl:apply-templates select="airports/airport">
    <xsl:with-param name="position" select="'start'" />
</xsl:apply-templates>

<!-- End -->
<xsl:apply-templates select="airports/airport">
    <xsl:with-param name="position" select="'end'" />
</xsl:apply-templates>

<xsl:template match="airports/airport">
    <xsl:param name="position" />
    <option value="{@iata}" data-alternative-spellings="{.},{@iata}">
        <xsl:if test="(@iata = 'LGW' and $position = 'start') or (@iata = 'LAX' and $position = 'end')">
            <xsl:attribute name="selected">selected</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="@iata"/> - <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </option>
</xsl:template>
```